# Excel doesn't close

Tags: c#, excel

I do everything. But "excel.exe" process doesn't close. 
If do`Excel.Visible = true`, window's excel close. But not process. Why?

```
Excel.Application excel = new Excel.Application();
Excel.Workbooks books = excel.Workbooks;
Excel.Workbook book = books.Add();
Excel.Sheets sheets = book.Sheets;
Excel.Worksheet sheet = sheets.Item[1];
foreach (Contract c in list){
     //sheet.Cells[i, 1] = some str;}
book.Close(true, @"some path");
books.Close();
excel.Quit();
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(sheet);
Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(sheet);
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(sheets);
Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(sheets);
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(book);
Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(book);
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(books);
Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(books);
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excel);
Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(excel);

GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
Console.Read();
```

Comment: Have you tried closing your `workbook` before quitting?

Comment: Yes, added code

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17131389/17034

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This work for me:

**Release (no Debug)**

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
//..
Excel.Application excel = new Excel.Application();
Workbook book = excel.Workbooks.Add();
Worksheet sheet = book.Sheets.Item[1];
try
{
    //int i = 2;
    //foreach ()
    //{
    //sheet.Cells[i, 1] = ...;
    //i++;
    //}
}
catch { }
finally
{
    book.Close(true, @"path");
    excel.Quit();
}
Console.Read();
```

**if Debug - doesn't work.**